# If $T:V\to W$ is an isomorphism, is $\det([T]_\beta^{T(\beta)})$ independent of the choice of a basis $\beta$ for $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to W$ be an isomorphism between finite-dimensional vector spaces. I'd like to determine whether or not $\det([T]_\beta^{T(\beta)})$ is independent of the choice of a basis $\beta$ for $V$. Here $[T]_\beta^{T(\beta)}$ denotes the matrix representation of $T$ relative to $\beta,T(\beta)$. Intuitively, the answer should be positive, and I'm working on the proof:

Let $\beta,\gamma$ be bases for $V$. Our goal is to show that
$$\det([T]_\beta^{T(\beta)})=\det([T]_\gamma^{T(\gamma)}).$$
A little knowledge of linear algebra would tell us that
$$[T]_\beta^{T(\beta)}=\left([I_W]_{T(\beta)}^{T(\gamma)}\right)^{-1}[T]_\gamma^{T(\gamma)}[I_V]_\beta^\gamma.\tag{$*$}$$
Now employ the fact that $T$ is an isomorphism to write
$$[I_V]_\beta^\gamma=[T^{-1}]_{T(\gamma)}^\gamma[T]_\beta^{T(\gamma)}$$
and
$$[I_W]_{T(\beta)}^{T(\gamma)}=[T]_\beta^{T(\gamma)}[T^{-1}]_{T(\beta)}^\beta,$$
where $I_V$ is the identity operator on $V$, and so on. You know I'm gonna plug these two equations into ($*$), but before doing so, I want you to recall that
$$[T^{-1}]_{T(\beta)}^\beta=\left([T]_\beta^{T(\beta)}\right)^{-1},$$
which will be used in our computation. Okay, we are good to go. After plugging them into the equation and taking the determinants of both sides, I ended up with
$$1=1.$$
What!?!? Did I miss something important? How could I obtain the desired result? Thank you.

Comment: The answer is no (you didn't miss anything). Pretty much from definition, it follows that for any isomorphism $T:V\to W$, and any ordered basis $\beta$ of $V$, we have $T(\beta)$ is an ordered basis of $V$ and $[T]_{\beta}^{T(\beta)}=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of appropriate size. So, it is perfectly correct that the determinant is $1$. Note that if you modified the bases used then you'd get a different answer (still non-zero, but different).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, but what do you mean by modifying the bases used?

Comment: I just mean that if $\gamma$ is an arbitrary basis of $W$ (not necessarily $T(\beta)$), then $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ will be an invertible matrix, not necessarily identity. In fact, suppose $V,W$ are $n$-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$, and $T:V\to W$ an isomorphism. Then, for any invertible matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$, there exist ordered bases $\beta$ of $V$, $\gamma$ of $W$ such that $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=A$. So, $\det ([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma})=\det A\in F\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. You've been most helpful. Honestly, I didn't notice that $[T]_{\beta}^{T(\beta)}$ is the identity matrix, which is really beyond my expectation. Again, thank you.